# Javascript auto "transform: scale()" iframe, preserving aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to show a couple of iframes in my site, but want them to be responsive - keeping their aspect ratio (16:9) - and scale their contents using CSS scale() function - so preserving actual frame width & height.

Below you may find my attempt, which works fine on page load, but it's not responsive on page resize.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame'),
iframeinitialwidth = $('iframe').width();

jQuery.fn.fitToParent = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        var $iframe = jQuery(this);
        var width = $iframe.width();
        var height = $iframe.height();
        var parentWidth = $iframe.parent().width();
        var parentHeight = $iframe.parent().height();

        var aspect = width / height;
        var parentAspect = parentWidth / parentHeight;

        if (aspect > parentAspect) {
            newWidth = parentWidth;
            newHeight = newWidth / aspect;
        } else {
            newHeight = parentHeight;
            newWidth = newHeight * aspect;
        }
        
    });
    var scaleFactor = newWidth/iframeinitialwidth;
    $('iframe').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')', '-webkit-transform-origin': '0 0'});
   
};

$('.frame').fitToParent();

$( window ).resize(function() {
    console.log("resizing window");
    $('.frame').fitToParent();
});
```

```css
.frame-wrapper{
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.frame {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-4 px-2">
        <div class="col ms-sm-auto col-lg-12 px-md-4">
          <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-3 my-4">
              <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header">Test</h5>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="frame-wrapper">
                    <iframe frameborder="no" class="frame" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" id="frame" width="1280px" height="720px"></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-3 my-4">
              <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header">Test</h5>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="frame-wrapper">
                    <iframe frameborder="no" class="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquisition_of_Twitter_by_Elon_Musk" id="frame" width="1280px" height="720px"></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-3 my-4">
              <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header">Test</h5>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="frame-wrapper">
                    <iframe frameborder="no" class="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_French_presidential_election" id="frame" width="1280px" height="720px"></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-3 my-4">
              <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header">Test</h5>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="frame-wrapper">
                    <iframe frameborder="no" class="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_the_Moskva" id="frame" width="1280px" height="720px"></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You gave the `.frame-wrapper` a specific width and height after this has run the first time, so the next time you are reading these, you will get exactly those values back. Your wrapper does _not_ get wider or narrower any more when you make the browser window wider/narrower - _because_ you set it to a specific width.

Comment: @CBroe, e removed that part of script where Width & Height of `.frame-wrapper` is set. Now the iframe is responsive, but height of `.frame-wrapper` remains at 720px (the red part). How can I fix that?

Comment: Might make more sense to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio perhaps, for the container.

Comment: @CBroe, I've applied aspect ratio to the container `.frame-wrapper { aspect-ratio: 16 / 9; }`, but that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: With that, it should keep the correct aspect ratio. If you now make the wrapper position relative, then you can position the iframe absolute in it, so that it automatically stretches across the whole element - by setting all four "coordinates" to 0, and width/height to auto.